ASP.Net Create Html String
With ASP.NET, I want to create a html file in a controller. I researched and found out that .cshtml file create HTML view when ASP.NET MVC response send through middleware. Therefore it could be difficult to create .html text file in a controller of ASP.NET MVC.
After creating a .html file, I also want convert the .html file into a PDF file using WkHtmltoPdf, which is open-source command line tool.
I tried with this code I've written:
public IActionResult Pdf()
{
    // Want to create a html string here. No html string is created......
    var viewHtml =  View("Pdf", invoice).ToString();

    // Want to convert a thml string into pdf here.
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
                  {
                      FileName = @"C:\test\wkhtmltopdf.exe",
                      Arguments = viewHtml + " " + pdfPath,
                  };
    var process = Process.Start(psi);
}


Why do you create HTML file first, only to convert it to PDF ? Why not just create the PDF file from the beginning, and use a toolkit that supports this natively?

Thank you K J.   I didn't know "msedge.exe" is able to create df file from html.  So, I will try instead.

Thank you marc_s for the comment.  The reason why I want use Razor Engin is this. First, I want to use same format.  Secondly, in the same format, I want to change some content.  Let's say, invoice is send to a client every month, the invoice-format should be same but the prices, quantity, or issued date shall be differ.

Appreciate it, K J.
